# Stepper motor doesn't spin - it just vibrates

Tags: stepper-motor, driver

I’m using a NEMA17 stepper motor (17HS4401) and TMC2225 driver (upgraded from TMC2208) for my artwork.

It had a problem after about 3 weeks since the exhibition started.
The motor vibrated loudly and didn’t spin.

I’ve been tried some steps for fixing it, and I just need help for guessing what the problem is.

As the code I programmed, the motor had been spun at a speed with 500 microseconds delay per a step.

I set 9 V for the motor.

It spun 8 hours per a day during the last 3 weeks.

For the first, I guessed ‘9 V is too high for the motor?’ So I decreased it to 5 V.

It looked fine at that time and worked for a day.

At the next day, however, it vibrated again when the power supplied.

When I searched about the rated voltage of stepper motor, I realized the higher voltage will be okay.

For the second step, I increased the voltage to 12 V, and I changed the motor (17HS4401) to the stronger (17HS8401) because I also worried about the torque.

[image]

It looked fine at that time, and after 3 days the same problem happened again.

This is my guess:

From the first, 9 V wasn’t enough, so over current flowed on the driver. As a result, the driver died.

I changed the driver and it looks fine now, but, I'm worrying if it is the appropriate solution.

Comment: this might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135191/rpi-pico-micropythpn-controlling-tmc2208-tmc2209-tmc2225-stepper-motor-drive

Comment: The packaged driver modules have a trimpot for setting the drive current. What did you set it to?  Also, in both cases the driver failed, is that correct?

Comment: That driver has a rated current of 1.4A with a peak of 2A.  Your motors are rated at 1.5A.  This would explain why your driver fails after a period of time and your motor vibrates as one phase is burnt out.  Driver with more capability.  Or possibly (slim) a heatsink on driver.

Comment: Thank you all. @StainlessSteelRat As I guessed, When the voltage increases, does the current flowed on the driver get lower? I used 24V 5A(120W) SMPS and a step down module. Is the unused current consumed by heat at smps? Or do I need to decrease amp of power supply itself?